# How to insert an external image in an Office addin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerpoint, office-js

I would like to insert an image into a PowerPoint slide using `setSelectedDataAsync` and `Office.CoercionType.Image` like:

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(image, {
    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
    imageLeft: 5,
    imageTop: 5,
    imageWidth: 100,
    imageHeight: 100
});
```

That system works for assets, I just have to insert the image into a canvas and then convert it to data URL:

```
const image = new Image();
image.src = props.url;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

And then we just insert the canvas to the slide:

```
var cvs = canvas.current;
var result = cvs.toDataURL().split(",")[1];
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(result, {
    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
    imageLeft: 5,
    imageTop: 5,
    imageWidth: canvas.current.width / 3,
    imageHeight: canvas.current.height / 3
});
```

The problem is that this system does not work for external images. I get the error "SecurityError" because once an external image is inserted in the canvas, the clean-origin flag is set to false. How can I insert external images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/powerpoint-tutorial#insert-an-image) to insert an image in your Office Add-in.

Comment: This is for C#. I'm using Office.js with React

Comment: @PauRosello Nope, it's for React.JS :) .. for Office.JS add-ins :)